# Is it possible to run on heroku non web java application?

Tags: java, heroku

I want to run a java application that is not webapp
I tried the worker process, but as I understand, this is just an additional process that works with the web process. On heroku I got Error H14 (No web processes running). But **I DON'T HAVE A WEB PROCESS**.

Too long to describe what kind of application I have. But let's say this is just an application with one `App` class and one `main` method, which will just output `"Hello world!"`

How to make only Hello world application work in a heroku project without any web part?
It is maven project

Comment: That error pops up if you are visiting the webpage of your app. Don't visit the webpage of your app and you don't see that error. It will also have no impact on your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this error pops up if you are visiting the webpage of your app. If you just don't visit your app's webpage, this error doesn't appear and your app works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your application should communicate through HTTP protocol as web API, then you will be able to publish it as a web service, otherwise, it's just a console application that should be downloaded as .jar file and runnable on the user's host machine